# Add notice to add image popup

Tags: post-thumbnails, globals

I have been using the global `$pagenow` variable to add instructions for users, but I need to somehow hook into the add image popup as I would like to instruct the users on optimal resolution for featured images.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using a plugin for the popup then simply add the notice in the Pop-up's parent 'div' using html tags in the template file. This will help you achieve what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using the default WordPress media pop-up.

Comment: Yes i understand that you want to add a notice in your default add media WordPress popup. If you are familiar actions and filters in WordPress then you can use this filter: media_upload_tabs